# array_push multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following codeline

```
$return_array = array(
            $count_answers => array(
                    "name" => $domain,
                    "type" => $type,
                    "class" => $class,
                    "ttl" =>$ttl,
                    "data_lenght" => $data_l
                    )
     );
```

I want to add `preference` after data length with the following code

```
array_push($return_array[$count_answers]['preference'], $preference);
```

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in \functions\functions.php on line 367

why is my first parameter not an array?

Comment: Using array_push would be adding another 'row' to your array. All you are doing is adding another **attribute** to your 'row'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there's no element in `$return_array` indexed by `'preference'`. You can append `$preference` with this instead

```
$return_array[$count_answers]['preference'][] = $preference;
```

or initialize with an empty array first

```
$return_array[$count_answers]['preference'] = array();
```

If you don't want to add an *array* of preferences, but just one element `'preference'`, append it with

```
$return_array[$count_answers]['preference'] = $preference;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `array_push`, you can add the item directly.

```
$return_array[$count_answers]['preference'] = $preference;
```

`array_push` does not allow string as indexes, so your `$preference` would be at `$return_array[$count_answers][0]`

On your line 367, your are not providing an array, but an empty element in your current array.

Answer (score 1):

You should correct your code with below.

```
$return_array = array(
        $count_answers => array(
                "name" => $domain,
                "type" => $type,
                "class" => $class,
                "ttl" =>$ttl,
                "data_lenght" => $data_l
                )
 );

$preference['preference'] = "kkk";
```

Just change

```
$return_array[$count_answers]['preference']
```

with

```
$return_array[$count_answers]
```

in array_push, like below

```
array_push($return_array[$count_answers], $preference);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array_push() with a multidimensional array is an oxymoron.

PHP arrays are hierarchical - not multi-dimensional. And array_push adds a numbered element with the specified value. Further, the usage of array_push() is clearly explained in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

> I want to add 'preference' after data length with the following code

Why do you want to do it with that code? It's failing and the reason should be obvious.

The code you should you should be using is:

```
$return_array[$count_answers]['preference']=$preference;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr_data_arrays as $key=>$line_arr) { // do an array looping at first

        $new_arr = array(); // create an array to be included on the second position
        $new_arr[0] = $line_arr;

        array_push($arr_data_arrays[$key][1],$new_arr);//include the whole array on the sec position
};
```

Easy like that!